# Delayed::Job hooks and deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, rails-activejob, rollbar

In the README, under Rails Mailers (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/#rails-mailers), it states

> You may also wish to consider using Active Job with Action Mailer which provides convenient .deliver_later syntax that forwards to Delayed Job under-the-hood.

This seems misleading to me, since it appears much of the Delayed Job functionality stops working. The statement "forwards to Delayed Job under-the-hood", makes it sound like DelayedJob is still in control. Can anyone confirm or clear up my misunderstanding?

I've been using DelayedJob for a long time and at some point started using `deliver_later` based on that comment in the Readme.

I've just started using custom jobs and am also cleaning up my Rollbar integration.  In the section on Hooks (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks), it states:

> NOTE: If you are using ActiveJob these hooks are not available to your jobs. You will need to use ActiveJob's callbacks. You can find details here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#callbacks

I have since experimented with this by throwing an exception inside of a mailer and noticed that mail sent with `deliver_later` is not being reported to DelayedJob as a failed jobs or retried as configured in DelayedJob.

I've also noticed that Rollbar integration ties into the the DelayedJob :failure hook (https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/rollbar/plugins/delayed_job/plugin.rb).

By stating that Active Mailer "provides convenient .deliver_later syntax that forwards to Delayed Job under-the-hood", it wasn't clear that I was missing out on DelayedJob retry and failure logic...and Rollbar's DelayedJob integration.

**I believe a warning should be added stating the caveats** since many new users won't read/assimilate all of the details about custom jobs and hooks at first go.

**Is the following true?** "When using `deliver_later` instead of `delay`, the DelayedJob Hooks will not be called and thus DelayedJob's retry and failure handling will not be honored.  In this case, when using `deliver_later`, you should rely on ActiveJob exception handling."

| Environment |  |
| --- | --- |
| Rails | 5.2.8.1 |
| DelayedJob | 4.1.11 |
| Rollbar | 3.4.0 |

Comment: I am a bit confused by the question as it seems that it might answer itself. You asked: *"When using `deliver_later` instead of `delay`, the DelayedJob Hooks will not be called and thus DelayedJob's retry and failure handling will not be honored. In this case, when using `deliver_later`, you should rely on ActiveJob exception handling."* but also stated the docs say: *"If you are using ActiveJob these hooks are not available to your jobs. You will need to use ActiveJob's callbacks."*

Comment: @engineersmnky in my mind, the documentation contradicts itself.  I would create a GitHub Issue and possibly PR, but it appears the Issues, PR's, and the Google Group aren't currently being managed.  As a result, I came here in hopes of confirming what I suspect, so I can move ahead with confidence.  Then I'd love to work to clear up the documentation. As it is written, with those two statements in different sections, it's not clear to first-time users.